# Finding the root that minimize tree depth

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Giving a tree that content no cycles (eg a minimum spanning tree : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Minimum_spanning_tree.svg)
How to calculate which node minimize the tree depth if it is used as root ?

Comment: Clarify:  Are you asking, given a fully connected undirected acyclic graph, select the node for which the most distant node is nearest?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All trees contain no cycles.  By definition, a tree is an cycle-free, connected graph.  If there is one vertex, the answer is trivial.  So assume there are at least two vertices.

Let *u* and *v* be two vertices such that their distance *d* (*u*, *v*) is maximum.  It should be easy to see that if one selects a vertex along a shortest *uv* path to be the root, the depth will be at least *ceiling* (*d* (*u*, *v*) / 2).  It should also be noted that if one selects a vertex to be the root not on that path, the depth will be greater than *ceiling* (*d* (*u*, *v*) / 2).

Suppose that we have chosen the root *r* to be the middle vertex along a minimum *uv* path such that *d* (*u*, *r*) = *ceiling* (*d* (*u*, *v*) / 2) and *d* (*r*, *v*) ≤ *ceiling* (*d* (*u*, *v*) / 2).  If there were another vertex, *w*, such that *d* (*r*, *w*) > *ceiling* (*d* (*u*, *v*) / 2), we would have *d* (*u*, *r*) < *d* (*w*, *r*) and then, because there is only one path between any two distinct vertices in a tree, we have *d* (*u*, *v*) = *d* (*u*, *r*) + *d* (*r*, *v*) < *d* (*u*, *r*) + *d* (*r*, *w*) = *d* (*u*, *w*), which contradicts that *u* and *v* have the greatest distance.  So now the depth, given *r* as the root, is *ceiling* (*d* (*u*, *v*) / 2).

So we need to find the two vertices with the largest distance.  Once we do that, we can use a shortest path-finding algorithm for *uv*, note the length, and traverse half-way along said path and use that middle vertex as the root.

How do we find those vertices?  Pick a vertex *w* and place it in a queue.  While the queue is non-empty add the neighbors of the next vertex in the queue to the end of the queue.  When the queue is empty, take note of the most recently removed vertex.  This will be *u*.  Perform the procedure again and you will have *v*.

Why does this work?  The above algorithm finds a furthest away vertex from *w*. If *w* happens to be *u* or *v*, the algorithm clearly finds *v* or *u*, respectively.  So suppose *w* is neither *u* nor *v*.  If the algorithm found a *u* or *v* in the first pass, again, it will work (for it will find the other in the second pass), so assume, by way of contradiction, that after the first pass it found *x* such that it is not the end of a maximum path for the tree.  From the triangle inequality we have *d* (*u*, *v*) ≤ *d* (*u*, *w*) +  *d* (*w*, *v*) and *d* (*v*, *x*) ≤ *d* (*v*, *w*) + *d* (*w*, *x*).  Subtracting the second from the first we have *d* (*u*, *v*) - *d* (*v*, *x*) ≤ *d* (*u*, *w*) - *d* (*w*, *x*).  We can then rearrange that to *d* (*u*, *v*) + *d* (*w*, *x*) ≤ *d* (*u*, *w*) + *d* (*v*, *x*).  Since *d* (*w*, *u*) ≤ *d* (*w*, *x*) (*x* is the end of a maximum path from *w*; *wu* cannot exceed *wx*) and *d* (*v*, *x*) < *d* (*u*, *v*) (*x* is not the end of a maximum path), we can strengthen the inequality to *d* (*u*, *v*) + *d* (*w*, *x*) < *d* (*u*, *v*) + *d* (*w*, *x*).  That's not possible, though, so *x* must be at the end of a maximum path.

Comment: Thanks you  ! No other methods ?

Comment: My algorithm/method is exactly the same as Saeed's.  I just gave an explanation/proof for it so that you could read it and know that my answer is correct.  I could try to think of an alternative algorithm/method.  What's wrong with this one?

Comment: No problem with this one it works perfectly but i wonder if there are other ways to do this (Just out of curiosity)

Answer (score 8):

Find [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) of tree after that select middle node of diameter as root. For finding diameter run two BFS, first BFS starts from random node `v`, and finds farthest node from `v`, name it `x`, second BFS finds farthest node from `x` name it `y`. Now the path between `x` and `y` is diameter.

Comment: @nax, code for which part, if you have a good data structure for your tree you can simply use any of available sample BFS codes around web.

Comment: sorry for my english, i mean references not sources

Comment: @nax, my english is not better than you, but you want reference for which part? do you looking for proof (is not hard and is better try it yourself). but this is kind of folklore and well known problem and solution.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following algorithm may work (I did not verify it), starting from any tree representation of your graph.

```
S = set of all leaves of the tree
foreach node in S: mark(node)
repeat:
  # at each iteration, S is the set of all nodes at
  # a given min distance to a leave
  # initially this distance is 0, then 1, etc.
  S' = empty set
  foreach node in S:
    parent = parent(node)
    if !marked(parent): S' += parent; mark(parent)
  if S' is empty then S contains all innermost nodes, we are done
  S = S' and continue
```